# how to have SSM read-only permission (ssm:GetParameters) in the i am role

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-media-live

I am doing a simple setup of HLS/dash live streaming from an input source.I have used Open Broadcaster Software(OBS) to push a Live RTMP stream to Media Live.
but while creating medialive Channel i am getting this validation error.
*Validation Errors*

/medialive/tutorial1
Service failed to access the passwordParam '/medialive/tutorial1' in the Parameter Store. Please make sure the role 'arn:aws:iam::*************:role/MediaLiveAccessRole' has S
SM read-only permission (ssm:GetParameters) to access it and try again

And i also want to know that how can i integrate all these to ReactJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the required permissions to the role. Please have a look at this guide for reference: [Adding IAM Identity Permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_manage-attach-detach.html#add-policies-console)

Comment: Thanks,now its working but i want to clear my following doubts please explain (1).how to save my live streamed video   (2).In same time how multiuser can access this for coming live

Comment: Thanks for accepting this answer. I’m glad I could help. Regarding your other questions I think it would be best to post them as new questions to increase the chance for others to see.